# Why do I get a module missing error for a dependency that I added in maven , and i need to resolve it?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gson

`Error:(10, 18) java: package com.google.gson is not visible
  (package com.google.gson is declared in module gson, but module AnimalShelter fails to read it)`

I'm getting this error after adding the **gson** dependency to my maven, I'm completely lost as to how to fix it, I've googled around and it was suggested I put a required in my  **module-info.java**. Did that, it fixes the IDE error but then when I try to run

`java.lang.module.FindException: Module gson not found, required by AnimalShelter`

I'm honestly not up to speed with how modules work at all so I might be overlooking somthing easy, but isn't it supposed to work after adding the dependency in my maven pom.xml? The pom.xml snippet is shown below

pom.xml: (imported)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>AnimalShelterYori</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../mods</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<dependencies>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Gson `<scope>provided</scope>` ... is it really provided by something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try below options:

1. The scope of Gson dependency is **provided** so make sure at runtime this will be provided by any container
2. Update the maven project and do clean install
3. Try using latest version of Gson

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.5</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>`

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem was that the scope on my dependency. Taking away the 'provided' scope fixed the issue, I can't remember why I added it in the first place but I suppose the issue was that gson wasn't being provided by a container

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven's [provided](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) scope implies the dependency does not need to be packaged with your application (i.e. you're deploying to an app server like Tomcat that will provide the dependency). Try removing the scope all together or change to the default of **compile**.